# using document.readyState correctly with Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm searching for a way to scroll down to a page that loads content as it is scrolled, to have everything loaded before I start interacting with it using Selenium.

I found this code below which was posted for c#, I changed it to Java. It compiles and runs. But even though the page reaches the end, it does not get out of the loop

```
        Boolean readyStateComplete = false;
        while (!readyStateComplete)
        {
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            executor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight)");
            readyStateComplete = (String) executor.executeScript("return document.readyState") == "complete";
        }
```

I don't know much about Javascript. How can this be corrected?

Comment: try **.equals()** method instead of *==* i means 

readyStateComplete = ((String) executor.executeScript("return document.readyState")).equals("complete");

Comment: that did it. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `.equals()` method instead of `==` i means

```
readyStateComplete = ((String) executor.executeScript("return document.readyState")).equals("complete");
```

> == tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
>
> .equals() tests for value equality (whether they are logically
>   "equal").

Answer (score 1):

A better way to scroll down the page and wait for the content to be loaded is to use `executeAsyncScript` and then wait for the scroll height to change and for the state to be ready:

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

driver.get("http://imgur.com/");

final String JS_SCROLL_DOWN =
    "var callback = arguments[0], page = document.documentElement, height = page.scrollHeight; " +
    "window.scrollTo(0, height); " +
    "(function fn(){ " +
    "   if(page.scrollHeight != height && document.readyState == 'complete') " +
    "      return callback(); " +
    "   setTimeout(fn, 30); " +
    "})();";

js.executeAsyncScript(JS_SCROLL_DOWN);
```